# Logic normals forms, wolfram, problem.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is formula which I must write as CNF, DNF and Negation of formula as CNF and DNF:
$$(p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow ((p \rightarrow \neg r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow \neg q))$$

After I get rid of the implications I got something like this (DNF FORM):
$$(p \wedge q \wedge r) \vee (p \wedge \neg r) \vee \neg p \vee \neg q$$

And this is the answer in my book, but what's the difference between a good answer and [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Implies%28Implies%28p%2CImplies%28q%2Cr%29%29%2C%20Implies%28Implies%28p%2Cr%29%2CImplies%28p%2C~q%29%29%29/)'s?

One more question. How can i turn it to CNF ?

Comment: The difference is that your answer, if correct, isn't fully simplified which isn't to say it is wrong.

Comment: Could some help me how can i create from this CNF form?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(p→(q→r))→((p→¬r)→(p→¬q))$ is a tautology.

There's a typo in [your wolfram input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Implies%28Implies%28p%2CImplies%28q%2Cr%29%29%2C%20Implies%28Implies%28p%2Cr%29%2CImplies%28p%2C~q%29%29%29/). It should look like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Implies%28Implies%28p%2CImplies%28q%2Cr%29%29%2C+Implies%28Implies%28p%2C~r%29%2CImplies%28p%2C~q%29%29%29%2F), with the $r$ in $(p \rightarrow \neg r)$  negated.

But your simplification is correct. It can be further simplified though.